# How make pdfplumber treat right vertical edge of a page as a table vertical line?

Tags: python, pdfplumber

How make pdfplumber treat right vertical edge of a page as a table vertical line?

I have pdf with cropped right edge, and that cut took away the rightmost vertical line of the table.

Answer (score -1):

One needs to do `page.extract_table()` with additional parameters, according to [documentation](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber):

```py
table_settings = {
    "vertical_strategy": "lines",
    "explicit_vertical_lines": [page.width],  # this thing
}

page.extract_table(table_settings)
```

`page.width` stores `x` coordinate for the rightmost pixel on page

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Comment: and what part of "# this thing" is equivocal?